# How to get number of groups in a groupby object in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to know how many unique groups I have to perform calculations.

Given a groupby object called `dfgroup`, how do we find the number of groups?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes), you can get the number of groups with `len(dfgroup)`.

Comment: As noted below, using `len(dfgroup)` can be very slow, especially for large number of groups. `dfgroup.ngroups` is the fastest way to get this, as this is a stored value!

Answer (score 122):

## Simple, Fast, and Pandaic: `ngroups`

Newer versions of the groupby API (pandas >= 0.23) provide this (undocumented) attribute which stores the number of groups in a GroupBy object.

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aabbcccd')})
dfg = df.groupby('A')
```

```
# call `.ngroups` on the GroupBy object
dfg.ngroups
# 4
```

Note that this is different from [`GroupBy.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html) which returns the actual groups themselves.

#### **Why should I prefer this over `len`?**

As noted in [BrenBarn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787977/4909087), you could use `len(dfg)` to get the number of groups. **But you shouldn't**. Looking at the [implementation of `GroupBy.__len__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L417-L418) (which is what `len()` calls interally), we see that `__len__` makes a call to [`GroupBy.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html), which returns a dictionary of grouped indices:

```
dfg.groups
{'a': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'b': Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 'c': Int64Index([4, 5, 6], dtype='int64'),
 'd': Int64Index([7], dtype='int64')}
```

Depending on the number of groups in your operation, **generating the dictionary only to find its length is a wasteful step**. `ngroups` on the other hand is a stored property that can be **accessed in constant time**.

This has been documented in [`GroupBy` object attributes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes). The issue with `len`, however, is that for a GroupBy object with a lot of groups, this can take a lot longer

#### But what if I actually want the size of each group?

You're in luck. We have a function for that, it's called `GroupBy.size`. But please note that `size` counts NaNs as well. If you don't want NaNs counted, use `GroupBy.count` instead.

Comment: @U9-Forward Thanks! It isn't a popular question (relatively speaking) but I assume the upvotes here mean the answer is useful. I still feel like I can make improvements so I'll look into that in a bit.

Comment: Note `len(g)` can be *VERY* slow the first time it is called if there are a large number of groups!! IPython caches the result thereafter, but `g.ngroups` is always fast since it is stored as an attribute.

Comment: I guess a potential downside to `ngroups` is that being undocumented, it may break without notice in future pandas versions?