# Check if Pandas Groupby is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a usecase , where I m filtering on a `row_key` which is being supplied as an argument

I m aware of the standard `empty` property to check for a `DataFrame` , however could not find a similar one for `DataFrameGroupBy`

Below is a code snippet that demonstrates the usecase , the data supplied is dummy -

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Name,Value,row_key,row_label
XYZ,100,abc,"Label - 2"
ASD,100,abc,"Label - 2"
GHJ,1000,abc,"Label - 2"
KLI,100,abc,"Label - 2"
BHY,1009,bnm,"Label - 2"
TGB,1409,bnm,"Label - 2"
YUJ,1509,bnm,"Label - 2"
KUT,1609,bnm,"Label - 2"
"""))

invalid_row_key = 'fgh'

filter_df = df[df['row_key'] == invalid_row_key].groupby('row_label')

#### I want something similar to below if case , to handle if the filter_df is empty
if filter_df.empty:
   print("No Row Key Present")
```

I m aware I can use `recent_index` on the grouped-dataframed , but I wanted to check if there is a better way of handling this

Comment: How about just checking `df[df['row_key'] == invalid_row_key]` is empty before groupby-ing?

Comment: Yes Chris , Now I think about it , this makes way more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the `.ngroups` attribute, at least 1 group should be present for >= 1 rows:

```
if not filter_df.ngroups:
    # no row key present
```

See [this post by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512052/4909087) for more on `ngroups`.

---

The answer above assumes you cannot tell in advance of creating a groupBy object, but if you can, it is better to check at the condition step, then you can check the `DataFrame.empty` attribute instead which is more intuitive:

```
filter_df = df[df['row_key'] == invalid_row_key]
if filter_df.empty:
    # no rows present
else:
    filter_df.groupby('row_label').doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: This makes abs sense , I ended up using `size().empty` for now , but this is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would to filter the `dataframe` before the grouping condition as stated by other answers.

However I tried the following solution myself .

```
if filter_df.size().empty:
   print("Empty DataFrame")
```